# How to rename multiple files with random names together

Tags: perl, file-rename

I have files with random names and i want to rename all them together like Trace1, Trace2 and so on.... any idea?

Comment: What does "rename together" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# use dirname() to keep the renamed files in the same directory
use File::Basename qw( dirname );

my $i = 1;
for my $file (@ARGV) {
    rename $file, dirname($file) . "/Trace$i"; 
    print "$file -> Trace$i\n";
} continue { $i++ }
```

If you are new to Linux, you need to also remember to make the script executable (assuming the script was saved in the file named `random-renamer`):

```
chmod 755 random-renamer
```

And then to run it (rename all the files in the `random-files` directory):

```
./random-renamer random-files/*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a shell command:

```
i=1;
for f in *
do
    mv $f "Trace$i"
    i=$(($i+1))
done
```

Comment: You can execute that in the shell (copy and paste it). But be careful: the code right now will rename all files in the current directory. If you want just a certain set of files (like all .txt files), then replace `*` with a list or another pattern that describes them (e.g., `*.txt`).

Comment: Also, it assumes that there is no existing files matching `Trace*`

Comment: You can also easily replace the `*` with a command that filters out `Trace` files: `for f in $(ls * | grep -v ^Trace)`. Too simple a task for an actual script.

Comment: @Gingi: that will not work if there are file names with spaces. Backticks to drive a `for` loop are often problematic, and parsing `ls` output basically always is. `for f in *; do case $f in Trace*) continue;; esac; ... done` is a good workaround.

Comment: The `((i+1))` construct is a Bashism. It will not work in basic Bourne shell.

Answer (score 0):

This checks if there are any existing files named `Trace#` and avoids clobbering them.

```
use Path::Class qw( dir );
use List::Util  qw( max );

my $dir = dir(...);

my @files =
   map $_->basename(),
    grep !$_->is_dir(),
     $dir->children();

my $last =
   max 0,
    map /^Trace([0-9]+)\z/,
     @files;

my $errors;
for (@files) {
   my $old = $dir->file($_);
   my $new = $dir->file("Trace" . ++$last);
   if (!rename($new, $old)) {
      warn("Can't rename \"$old\" to \"$new\": $!\n");
      ++$errors;
   }
}

exit($errors ? 1 : 0);
```